# How to show that $A(3k, 2k)=4$?

Tags: coding-theory

Denote by $A(n,d)$ the maximal size of a binary code of length $n$ with distance $d$.

How to show that $A(3k, 2k)=4$? From Plotkin bound: $$2k > \dfrac{3k}{2} \Rightarrow A(3k, 2k) \leq 4$$ But I don't know why here equality. I also tried to use Gilbert–Varshamov lower bound. But it doesn't help to obtain $A(3k, 2k) \geq 4$.

Comment: For a lower bound, you can just construct such code directly.

Comment: @Dmitry: you mean for any k?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4402694/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/149865/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (linear) code attaining the bound:
$$
000\\011\\101\\110
$$
Each bit represents a block of $k$ equal bits.